# Bibliography won't compile (with biblatex package)

Tags: biblatex, biber

When editing bib file I faced a problem, which seems to be connected to either biblatex package or biber or their compatibility. Before I made some changes in one of the fields (I think it was a “translator” field) of one of the bibliography items in the bib file, everything worked just fine. After this change was made I received the error message. I undid the change, but the problem kept coming back and it affected all my tex documents with enabled `biblatex` package. The log has the following entries:

```
Package biblatex Warning: File 'MWE.bbl' is wrong format version - expected 2.7
LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 36.
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file: 
(biblatex)                MWE
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

I checked the compatibility matrix in the `biblatex` documentation, according to which biber 2.5 is compatible with `biblatex 3.4`. And that’s exactly what I have.
MWE of a tex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{cmap}               
\usepackage{mathtext}           
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}       
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} 
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage[blocks]{authblk}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xparse}
\frenchspacing
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,sorting=nyt,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=999,style=gost-authoryear,language=auto,autolang=other]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\addbibresource{GOST.bib}



\begin{document}

\author[i]{И.\,О.~Фамилия1}

\affil[i]{affil1 }


\title{Название}
\date{}

\maketitle

\lipsum
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The bib file:

```
@article{reverberi2012deduction,
    title={Deduction without awareness},
    author={Reverberi, Carlo and Pischedda, Doris and Burigo, Michele},
    journal={Acta psychologica},
    volume={139},
    number={1},
    pages={244--253},
    year={2012},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{lisanyuketal,
    title={From the neuron doctrine to neural networks},
    author={Лисанюк, Елена Николаевна and Грфцова, Ирина Николаевна and Мигунов, Анатолий Иванович},
    journal={Журнал по аргументации},
    volume={16},
    number={8},
    pages={487--497},
    year={2015}
}
```

Edit

The file list from the log:

```
*File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size12.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
    cmap.sty    2008/03/06 v1.0h CMap support: searchable PDF
mathtext.sty    1999/01/28 v1.0 transparent text-and-math defs
 fontenc.sty
  t2aenc.def    2005/09/27 v1.0i Cyrillic encoding definition file
  t2acmr.fd    2001/08/11 v1.0a Computer Modern Cyrillic font definitions
inputenc.sty    2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
  t2aenc.dfu    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
   babel.sty    2016/04/23 3.9r The Babel package
 english.ldf    2012/08/20 v3.3p English support from the babel system
russianb.ldf    2016/02/18 1.3h Russian support for the Babel system
indentfirst.sty    1995/11/23 v1.03 Indent first paragraph (DPC)
letltxmacro.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 authblk.sty    2001/02/27 1.3 (PWD)
hyperref.sty    2016/05/05 v6.83n Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2016/05/10 v0.21 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2016/05/16 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2016/05/05 v6.83n Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
   puenc.def    2016/05/05 v6.83n Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 hpdftex.def    2016/05/05 v6.83n Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
  xparse.sty    2016/05/18 v6512 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2016/05/18 v6512 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2016/05/18 v6512 L3 programming layer 
l3pdfmode.def    2016/03/26 v6465 L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
  lipsum.sty    2014/07/27 v1.3 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text
biblatex.sty    2016/05/14 v3.4 programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)
   iftex.sty    2013/04/04 v0.2 Provides if(tex) conditional for PDFTeX, XeTeX,
 and LuaTeX
etoolbox.sty    2015/08/02 v2.2a e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
  logreq.sty    2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
  logreq.def    2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
 xstring.sty    2013/10/13  v1.7c  String manipulations (C Tellechea)
  blx-dm.def
biblatex-gost.dbx
gost-authoryear.dbx
biblatex-dm.cfg
blx-compat.def    2016/05/14 v3.4 biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.def    2016/05/14 v3.4 biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex-gost.def    2016/04/05 v1.6 biblatex-gost styles
gost-standard.bbx    2016/04/05 v1.6 biblatex-gost styles
gost-authoryear.bbx    2016/04/05 v1.6 biblatex-gost styles
gost-authoryear.cbx    2016/04/05 v1.6 biblatex-gost styles
biblatex.cfg    
csquotes.sty    2016/01/31 v5.1g context-sensitive quotations (JAW)
csquotes.def    2016/01/31 v5.1g csquotes generic definitions (JAW)
csquotes.cfg    
 russian.lbx    2016/05/14 v3.4 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
russian-gost.lbx    2016/04/05 v1.6 biblatex-gost styles
 english.lbx    2016/05/14 v3.4 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
 nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
     MWE.out
     MWE.out
     MWE.bbl
 ***********
```

`.blg` file from another document:

```
[0] Config.pm:340> INFO - This is Biber 2.4
[0] Config.pm:343> INFO - Logfile is 'document-ENG.blg'
[38] biber-MSWIN64:287> INFO - === 
[59] Biber.pm:347> INFO - Reading 'document-ENG.bcf'
[154] Biber.pm:738> INFO - Using all citekeys in bib section 0
[194] Biber.pm:3150> INFO - Processing section 0
[276] Biber.pm:3307> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'Harvard.bib' for section 0
[278] bibtex.pm:1124> INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
[279] bibtex.pm:985> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'Harvard.bib'
[361] UCollate.pm:65> INFO - Overriding locale 'ru-RU' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
[361] UCollate.pm:65> INFO - Overriding locale 'ru-RU' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
[361] Biber.pm:3027> INFO - Sorting list 'nyt/global' of type 'entry' with scheme 'nyt' and locale 'ru-RU'
[366] bbl.pm:519> INFO - Writing 'document-ENG.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
[367] bbl.pm:615> INFO - Output to document-ENG.bbl
```

Comment: Delete the `.bbl` and try again. If the version mismatch continues to be reported make sure you actually call the versions of the packages your package manager reports. Check with `biber --version` and add `\listfiles` to the very top of your `.tex` file and check the end of your `.log` file for the `biblatex` version.

Comment: Well if biblatex says the bbl has wrong format I normally trust it. What does the log-file and the blg-file say about the versions?

Comment: Deleting the bbl-file didn't help. Both `biber --version` check and log-file showed that I use version 2.5. After I faced the problem I reinstalled biber, and since then compilation doesn't create blg-file. However, I opened a blg-file from one of the documents I created earlier and it showed that the version of biber I was using is 2.4. Anyway, I can assure you that the current version is 2.5 (I downloaded and installed it today). The `biblatex` version is definitely 3.4.

Comment: But can you be sure that you don't have multiple versions of `biblatex` and Biber on your machine? Maybe the wrong version is picked up. We need to see the `.log` (best with `\listfiles`) and `.blg` files to be sure. Did you (re-)install Biber manually? If you have done so, please remove all manual installations and install the programme via your TeX distribution (on MikTeX use the Package Manager on TeX live use `tlmgr`.)

Comment: @moewe I added the file list in the question. Since Texstudio, as I mentioned earlier, won't create the blg file, I added the content of the file, from another tex document. Unfortunately, I can't add the entire log file, because I ran out of characters, so here is the dropbox link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/leox0v08acjf45z/MWE.log?dl=0. I also can't remove Biber.

Comment: Here is what I get when I try to remove Biber:

Executing action remove biber / tlmgr.pl: not removing biber.win32, needed by biber / 
tlmgr.pl: not removing biber, needed by collection-bibtexextra / 
tlmgr.pl: no packages removed.
tlmgr.pl: action remove returned an error; continuing.

Comment: Do you still run TeX live 2015? Somehow your versions of `biblatex` (3.4) and Biber (2.4, but should be 2.5) are out of sync? That shouldn't happen if you only install and update packages via `tlmgr`. If something is messed up now you might have to update to TeX live 2016. (But beware the LuaTeX issues.) (You don't need to uninstall the Biber version installed by `tlmgr`, only versions you may have installed manually.)

Comment: @moewe: I removed and reinstalled the latest version of TeX live yesterday.

Comment: Do you perhaps have multiple versions of TeX live/Biber/`biblatex` on your machine? Please run another update with `tlmgr`. Then try to compile the files again after removing the temporary files? What happens if you run `biber MWE`? What does the `.blg` say?

Comment: I ran `update --all` with `tlmgr` but the Biber version stayed 2.4. The same result I had after running `reinstall` command.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40942/discussion-between-moewe-and-david).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was caused by a version mismatch between Biber and `biblatex` that has since been resolved by the OP (see self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is solved. It is hard to detect what and when went wrong, but apparently after the conflict between Biber and `biblatex` occurred (although it is still a mystery why it did occur in the first place) updating the Biber version from 2.4 to 2.5 didn't help because my Avast antivirus was blocking the biber.exe file.